# when do i need to take into account the domain and range of an inverse function

Tags: trigonometry

I'm fairly new to inverse trigonometry and this might be a really stupid question but here goes: Let's say if you were asked a question what are the solutions to $\arcsin \frac12=A$, the answers would be $\frac\pi6$ and $\frac{5\pi}6$. However, the isn't the range of $\arcsin$ from $[\frac{-\pi}2, \frac\pi2]$? So how would $\frac{5\pi}6$ be a valid answer? And are there any such questions where I need to take into account the inverse range when solving for solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is a period function, so we can't obtain for every $x\in R$ the function $f^{-1}(x)$; we choose as invertibility range $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. So, we have:
$$\Im(\arcsin(x))=[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$$
and $$\Re(\arcsin(x))=[-1,1]$$

In your case, you were asked to determine $\arcsin(1/2)$. First, you can use the definition of $\arcsin(x)$ and obtain $\alpha=\pi/6$, but after that, you have to rember the graph of sine in $[0,2\pi]$ that is:

[image]

So, the other solution is $\alpha=\pi-\pi/6=5\pi/6$.